# Use ProgressDialog in a non activity class

Tags: android, android-activity, android-dialog, android-progressbar

I am using ProgressDialog in my activity which is called from a non-Activity Class.
Its throwing an error. Below are the two class how i tried to use ProgressDialog which it was not able to achieve.

MainActivity.java

```
public class LoginPage extends Activity {


LoginH appLogin;    
Context context;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {        
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login);

    Button  loginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bLogin);       
    context = LoginPage.this;

    loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        sDefault =  defaultText.getText().toString();

        appLogin = new LoginH(context);
        appLogin.execute(sDefault);         
        }
    });
}   
}
```

LoginH.java

```
public class LoginH extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

String urlLogin;
private Context context;

public LoginHmg(Context context){
    this.context = context;
}

ProgressDialog prg = new ProgressDialog(context);   
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) { 

    urlLogin ="xxx"
    WebServiceT wLoginApp = new WebServiceT();
    return wLoginApp.getMethod(urlLogin);
}   

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {     
    super.onPreExecute();       
    prg.show();
    prg.setMessage("Loading...");
    prg.setCancelable(false);       
}
}
```

Comment: what is the error???

Comment: Can you print the stacktrace of the error?

Comment: @JagadeshSeeram app crashes while initializing this ProgressDialog

Comment: at android.app.AlertDialog.resolveDialogTheme(AlertDialog.java:143)
at android.app.AlertDialog.<init>(AlertDialog.java:98)
at android.app.ProgressDialog.<init>(ProgressDialog.java:77)
at com.hmgps.ws.LoginH.<init>(LoginH.java:35)
at .ah.smenu.LoginPage$1.onClick(LoginPage.java:71)
@SamBains

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize the `ProgressDialog` in `onPreExecute`

```
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    prg = new ProgressDialog(context);
    prg.show();
    prg.setMessage("Loading...");
    prg.setCancelable(false);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Move your initialisation of the ProgressDialog Into the constructor. It's possible that context is null at the current point of initialisation.